# Evaluate SmoothBivariateSpline for two 1d array lists

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have three arrays `x,y,z`. I wanted to smooth the z-data. So, I have used `SmoothBivariateSpline` function. But when I eval the result, I get completely different values compared to my previous z-data. Below is my code:

```
def envinterpolate(x,y,z):

    x_interp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),len(x)*4)
    y_interp = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),len(x)*4)

    sbsp = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z)
    z_interp = sbsp.ev(x_interp,y_interp)

    return z_interp
```

Is there anything wrong in my code while evaluating the values of spline?
Attaching the plot,after trying s=0 parameter(redline my actual z-data,blackline z-interp data)

[image]

Comment: I would first use the base BivariateSpline (no smoothing), and make sure that it is returning the expected values (it should go through the original data points perfectly). If it doesn't, you have some mismatch in, for example, lengths. Next, when comparing z values are you taking in to account the fact that z_interp is not across the original x, y values, but is many times bigger?

Comment: Looking at the picture --- is your data actually 1-dimensional? It's a curve and not a surface. If so, you're basically asking the *surface interpolator* to extrapolate what the surface looks like, based on the single line on the x-y plane (IOW, wrong tool for the job). In the code you show, it's also not clear that the curve `(x_interp[i], y_interp[i])` has something to do with the original x,y. For interpolating 1D curves in 3D space, parametric splines (`splprep`) are the correct tool.

Comment: Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, *"smoothing"* refers specifically to cases where you *don't* want the interpolant to pass exactly through your input data points (for example if you know that your input data is noisy).

[`SmoothBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html) takes a parameter `s` that controls the degree of smoothing that is applied to the interpolant:

> **s** : *float, optional*
>
> Positive smoothing factor defined for estimation condition: `sum((w[i]*(z[i]-s(x[i], y[i])))**2, axis=0) <= s Default s=len(w)` which should be a good value if `1/w[i]` is an estimate of the standard deviation of `z[i]`.

If you don't want any smoothing you could simply set `s=0`.

Comment: Thanks ali_m, but my z-data values are much more apart I could see difference in 1000's. Maybe I could try just BivariateSpline

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you mean when you say that your *"z-data values are much more apart"*. Are you telling me that your interpolated values don't pass through your original datapoints even if you pass `s=0` to `SmoothBivariateSpline`?

Comment: Yes, attached a screenshot of my plot